# Duplicate zero eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What happens when you have two zero eigenvalues (duplicate zeroes) in a 2x2 system of linear differential equations?  For example,

$$\pmatrix{\frac{dx}{dt}\\\frac{dy}{dt}}=\pmatrix{1&1\\-1&-1}\pmatrix{x\\y}$$

has the characteristic polynomial $(1-\lambda)(-1-\lambda)+1=0$ which yields $\lambda=0$. Is this a center (since $Im(\lambda)=0$), a line of solutions (since $\lambda_i=0$), or what?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The same rules apply.

We would have the eigenvalue / eigenvectors:

- $\lambda_1 = 0, v_1 = (-1,1)$
- $\lambda_2 = 0, v_2 = (-1,0)$ (a generalized eigenvector)

If we solve this system, we would get:

- $x(t) = c_1(t+1) + c_2t$
- $y(t) = -c_1t + c_2(1-t)$

Can you use the eigenvalues/eigenvectors to figure that out due to the repeated eigenvalue?

**Update**

We can also plot a phase portrait for this system.

[image]